# org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility disable "save changes" dialog in resulting pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using the Apache PDFBox PDFMergerUtility to merge my PDFs for downloading.

My Code is the following (shortened):

```
private final PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();

public void merge(OutputStream outputStream, Collection<Bundle> attachments) {
    try {
        PDDocument mainDocument = new PDDocument();
        mainDocument.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(new PDAcroForm(mainDocument));
        for (Bundle bundle : attachments) {
            merger.addSource(bundle.getStream()); //The Input Stream of the PDF.
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        merger.setDestinationStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        merger.mergeDocuments();
        InputStream mergedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(mergedOutputStream.toByteArray());
        PDDocument mergedDocument = PDDocument.load(mergedInputStream);
        mergedDDocument.save(outputStream);
    } catch (COSVisitorException | IOException | BadSecurityHandlerException ex) {
    }
}
```

The PDFs are merged and I can open the PDF without any problems. There are no warnings or errors.

The problem comes with closing the PDF: 
Everytime I close the PDF, my PDF Reader (Adobe Acrobat Reader) asks me, if I like to save my changes. But I did not do any changes.

I know, that this behaviour is a result of the code above, as I also tested downloading a pdf without merging it with other PDFs.

Where does the behaviour come from and what can I do to stop my PDF reader to ask me, if I like to save the (non existing) changes?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use a `PDAcroForm`?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: And can you share a sample result PDF?

Comment: Some more code weirdness: no exception handling (please do at least output some logging), and mainDocument is never used. The "save changes" msg box comes when the Adobe Reader detects a malformed PDF.  Please try using the command line utility to merge and tell whether it works. https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#pdfMerger If not, please upload source and result pdfs somewhere.